# Oriented curve in two dimensions

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create a TikZ picture of a closed half circle centered at the origin with radius R in the plane. Here's what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [red,thick,domain=0:180] plot ({cos(\x)}, {sin(\x)});
\draw [red,thick,domain=0:180] plot ({cos(\x)},{0});
\draw [black,domain=-2:2] plot ({\x},{0});
\draw [black,domain=-1:1.5] plot ({0},{\x});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

That gives me my axes and my closed half circle.

Here's what else I'd like to have:

- Arrows on the curve indicating counterclockwise orientation
- Arrows on the positive ends of the positive axes
- Labels "R" and "-R" under the x-axis where the circle meets the axis
- A marking on the y-axis (maybe an "x") inside the curve

Are these simple additions? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I've edited it to include the document class and tikz package. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: Great. Please let me know if any further clarification is needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\scriptsize
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\path[<-] (2,0)node[right]{$x$} edge(-2,0) (0,1.5)node[above]{$y$} edge(0,-1);
\path[draw,red,thick, postaction={decorate,
         decoration={markings,
         mark=between positions 0.15 and 1 step 0.15 with {\arrow[blue]{>};}}}] 
         (0:1) node[below]{$R$} arc (0:180:1) node[below]{$-R$}--cycle;
\node at(0,.5){$\times$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that instead of drawing it with `plot`, I used the simple (single line) `arc` path, which enables you to do easy decorations. For this simple curve, using `plot` will not give you much power, but for complicated functions it is indispensable.

Comment: Almost entirely, yes! 

I want the red curve to connect -R and R on the x-axis as well. I'll try playing around with your code and see if I can get it to work.

Also, I want the "x" on the y-axis below the curve and above the x-axis. I'm guessing I would change your "\node at(0,1){$\times$};" to "\node at(0,0.5){$\times$};". 

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Okay, I've played around a little bit to no avail. How do I make a linear path from -R to R on the x-axis that is red and arrowed like the arc?

Comment: @pedrosuavo - Easy, see my edit. I only added the word `--cycle` for the `arc` path to close and changed `(0,1)` to `(0,.5)`. Good luck. Consider accepting the answer if you are happy with it.